# How to use Flutter SingleChildScroll view inside a ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

How to use SingleChildScroll view inside a ListView?

this is my current implementation

```
   ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 300,
                      child: const Text('Hello'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 300,
                      child: const Text('Sample events'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            //... more widgets here
          ],
        );
```

But I'm getting this errors when I scroll horizontally

```
 @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNewSource")
  external static _doThrowNewSource(
      String failedAssertion, int line, int column, Object? message);
```

Here's the design I wanted to solve.

[image]

Comment: I have no problem with your code.

Comment: just found out the answer right now. I just need to set the SingleChildScroll physics property to BouncingScrollPhysics(),

Answer (score 1):

**I'm Trying to Solve your Problem:**

> physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

```
ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: const Text('Hello'),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: const Text('Sample events'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //... more widgets here
      ],
    );
```